# Ps2pdf not working

Tags: texmaker, mactex, ps2pdf

I updated to the new MAC OS EL capitan and I am facing problems with my TeXmaker since then. I reinstalled the TeXmaker and MacTeX as it did not work after updating. I am trying to compile a TeX file using (`latex`,`bibtex`,`latex`,`latex`, `dvips` and `ps2pdf`). I am getting an error at `ps2pdf`.

> Error : could not start the command :
>   "/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/ps2pdf" "paper".ps

So I verified if `ps2pdf` is present in the folder and did not find it. I am not sure what to do. I searched for a solution but couldn't find an answer. Some posts with similar problem asked to change the path to `msg` but it did not work.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Some people don't work, and some people don't even appear at work...
Did you try to search for `ps2pdf`?  Is it in another folder, or is it not installed at all?

Comment: @jarauh I don't know what extension it should have. There is a pst2pdf in that folder but it is not an executable file( It says alias). However it is still not working. I guess we don't explicitly install that. I thought it comes with MacTeX by default

Comment: See also this post here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320057/ps2pdf-compilation-not-working-with-texstudio-el-capitan](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320057/ps2pdf-compilation-not-working-with-texstudio-el-capitan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ps2pdf exec should still be in /usr/local/bin so if you leave the path in ps2pdf in texmaker as it was prior to the El Capital upgrade then your typesetting should work fine. You can type "which ps2pdf" in OS terminal to check where the ps2pdf executable is located.

Comment: That totally worked. I found the path using the command and changed it in the preferences. Thanks a ton. I have been going crazy since morning to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might install ghostscript.

Firstly, make sure the command "brew" works. If not, please try to install" homebrew" via typing the following code in the Terminal

```
ruby -e"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, install ghostscript

```
brew install ghostscript
```